# Get models.ManyToManyField selected options count

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I can't figure out how to get the manytomanyfield selected options number

my code:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.first_name)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    authorsnumbers = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.authorsnumbers = self.authors.count()
        super(Event, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

if i select 2 authors, i want authorsnumber to be '2', but how?

Answer (score 0):

This would probably be an easier way to do it:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)

    def authorsnumbers(self):
        return self.authors.count()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

of course you could just use `book.authors.count()` instead of `book.authorsnumber()` wherever you need it.

Comment: yes but this is the same... but i want to save the authorsnumber variable. and .authors.count() doesn't work